# Create Multiple Threads that access the database simultaneously

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I have tried to locate the solutions to my problem in various message boards. However, I am running into walls. I am trying to recreate a problem that is happening on our database "LockWait Timeout" on a Mysql INNODB table. (for information about my issue I am trying to solve, go to: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10641 )I have narrowed down the issue, and I have a solution. But I cannot recreate the issue on a test environment so I can test my solution.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        

    System.out.println("Programm Starting");

    int numberOfthreads = 2;

    for(int x = 1; x <= numberOfthreads; x++){
        //Create the object UpdateClass


        // Create the Runable object
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            // Start the Runnable
            public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Running");
            }
        };

        Thread thr = new Thread(r);
        System.out.println("Thread object created");

        thr.start();
        final UpdateClass session = new UpdateClass(x);
        System.out.println("Thread object started");

        try {
            System.out.println("Starting UpdateClass.runProcess()");
            session.runProcess();
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        thr.stop();

        System.out.println("Thread stopped");
    }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to replicate simultaneous UPDATEs to the MySql table to create the LockWait Timeout issue.

My class UpdateClass works the way I need it to, but I cannot recreate the simultaneous events to call the class.

**Question**: How can I alter my code to increase the probability of generating the conditions that lead to the timeout?

Comment: what happens when you increase the thread timeout to perhaps 5000 ms or even higher?  I am assuming that in your code, you are using a transaction (with auto-commit off) to delete/update information in a table but put your thread to sleep for an extended period of time in order to trigger the lock timeout.  I am also assuming that the forum post you shared has the same MySQL version/patches that you are running in your test environment.

Comment: can you also share your mysql.cnf file - specifically the innodb_lock_wait_timeout.  Your lock timeout should exceed this limit to replicate the issue.

Comment: I did try and run at a 1000 threads.  I got MySql errors, just not the lockwait timeout errors I needed.

Answer (score 0):

few things you could try to replicate the issue in test:

1. change the innodb_lock_wait_timeout in the mysqlcnf to a small time interval or increase the thread sleep time (if you change the cnf file, you will need to restart the DB server)
2. Ensure that you are holding onto a lock (and have not released it) before the thread goes to sleep (you could possibly achieve the same with a network disconnect/DB connection going down while the lock has not been released but not entirely certain about that).

I am assuming that your MySQL version is the same as in production.

Comment: Changing the interval in the database is not what I need to do. the default is suffcient. What Iam having an issue with is creating simultaneous queries to the database.  This is a programming thing. I think I need to implement some type of recursion where multiple threads are being ran at the same time. The my code works right now is one thread works then finishes, then another thread starts....etc...this is not what I want.  I have tried many different loop configurations, but to no avail.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood - you are trying to replicate a prod issue in test.  The issue is that you experience lock_wait_timeout when using MySQL.  If you need to replicate the issue (lock_wait_timeout), you can repeat the steps mentioned above (in your code, you seem to be sleeping your thread to 1ms, increase it above the lock_time configured for MySQL, make sure that you hold onto the lock and do not give it up) - you should be able to replicate the timeout.

Comment: were you able to replicate the issue?